# Sed substitution possible with arithmetic involved?

Tags: regex, sed

File I need to modify contains the following:

```
block: 16, size: 16, start: 8, length: 4
```

I'd like the file so that values for **block**, **size** will be divided by 2 while values for **start**, **length** will be multiplied by 2.

Since I have to make such modifications for a whole bunch of files, I am considering using *Sed* to do the substitution work for me. But I'm not sure calculations are allowed in the matching and substituting process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always try to solve every problem tagged with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) using `sed`. But here it would be so easy to accomplish what you are trying to do with `awk`. (And the use of `sed` in this case is too difficult.) So, here is my solution using `awk`:

```
$ echo "block: 16, size: 16, start: 8, length: 4" | awk '{
    printf "%s %d, %s %d, %s %d, %s %d\n", $1, $2/2, $3, $4/2, $5, $6*2, $7, $8*2
}'
block: 8, size: 8, start: 16, length: 8
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected when the order of entries is different, e. g. `"block: 16, start: 8, size: 8, length: 4"`

Answer (score 8):

(The right tool to do this is awk, but for the fun of a sed exercise...)

It is possible in sed.  After all, a multiplication by 2 is set of substitution of the last digit according to some simple rules:

- 0 --> 0
- 1 --> 2
- 2 --> 4
- 3 --> 6
- ...
- 8 --> 16
- 9 --> 18

To take care of the carry digit, each rules should be written twice.

This sed script, that can be run with `sed -f script`, do the multiplication by 2 of all the numbers on the input lines:

```
s/$/\n\n/
:loop
s/0\n1\n/\n\n1/;t loop
s/0\n\n/\n\n0/;t loop
s/1\n1\n/\n\n3/;t loop
s/1\n\n/\n\n2/;t loop
s/2\n1\n/\n\n5/;t loop
s/2\n\n/\n\n4/;t loop
s/3\n1\n/\n\n7/;t loop
s/3\n\n/\n\n6/;t loop
s/4\n1\n/\n\n9/;t loop
s/4\n\n/\n\n8/;t loop
s/5\n1\n/\n1\n1/;t loop
s/5\n\n/\n1\n0/;t loop
s/6\n1\n/\n1\n3/;t loop
s/6\n\n/\n1\n2/;t loop
s/7\n1\n/\n1\n5/;t loop
s/7\n\n/\n1\n4/;t loop
s/8\n1\n/\n1\n7/;t loop
s/8\n\n/\n1\n6/;t loop
s/9\n1\n/\n1\n9/;t loop
s/9\n\n/\n1\n8/;t loop
s/\n1\n/\n\n1/;t loop
s/\(.\)\n\n/\n\n\1/;t loop
s/^\n\n//
```

Dividing an even number by 2, is the same logic, but from left to right instead of right to left:

```
s/^/\n\n/
:loop
s/\n1\n0/5\n\n/;t loop
s/\n\n0/0\n\n/;t loop
s/\n1\n1/5\n1\n/;t loop
s/\n\n1/\n1\n/;t loop
s/\n1\n2/6\n\n/;t loop
s/\n\n2/1\n\n/;t loop
s/\n1\n3/6\n1\n/;t loop
s/\n\n3/2\n1\n/;t loop
s/\n1\n4/7\n\n/;t loop
s/\n\n4/2\n\n/;t loop
s/\n1\n5/7\n1\n/;t loop
s/\n\n5/2\n1\n/;t loop
s/\n1\n6/8\n\n/;t loop
s/\n\n6/3\n\n/;t loop
s/\n1\n7/8\n\n/;t loop
s/\n\n7/3\n1\n/;t loop
s/\n1\n8/9\n\n/;t loop
s/\n\n8/4\n\n/;t loop
s/\n1\n9/9\n1\n/;t loop
s/\n\n9/4\n1\n/;t loop
s/\n1\n/5\n\n/;t loop
s/\n\n\(.\)/\1\n\n/;t loop
s/\n\n$//
```

Combining those, this script do the job:

```
h
s/, start.*//
s/^/\n\n/
t loopa
:loopa
s/\n1\n0/5\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n0/0\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n1\n1/5\n1\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n1/\n1\n/;t loopa
s/\n1\n2/6\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n2/1\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n1\n3/6\n1\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n3/2\n1\n/;t loopa
s/\n1\n4/7\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n4/2\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n1\n5/7\n1\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n5/2\n1\n/;t loopa
s/\n1\n6/8\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n6/3\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n1\n7/8\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n7/3\n1\n/;t loopa
s/\n1\n8/9\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n8/4\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n1\n9/9\n1\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n9/4\n1\n/;t loopa
s/\n1\n/5\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n\(.\)/\1\n\n/;t loopa
s/\n\n$//
H
g
s/.*, start/, start/
s/\n.*//
s/$/\n\n/
t loopb
:loopb
s/0\n1\n/\n\n1/;t loopb
s/0\n\n/\n\n0/;t loopb
s/1\n1\n/\n\n3/;t loopb
s/1\n\n/\n\n2/;t loopb
s/2\n1\n/\n\n5/;t loopb
s/2\n\n/\n\n4/;t loopb
s/3\n1\n/\n\n7/;t loopb
s/3\n\n/\n\n6/;t loopb
s/4\n1\n/\n\n9/;t loopb
s/4\n\n/\n\n8/;t loopb
s/5\n1\n/\n1\n1/;t loopb
s/5\n\n/\n1\n0/;t loopb
s/6\n1\n/\n1\n3/;t loopb
s/6\n\n/\n1\n2/;t loopb
s/7\n1\n/\n1\n5/;t loopb
s/7\n\n/\n1\n4/;t loopb
s/8\n1\n/\n1\n7/;t loopb
s/8\n\n/\n1\n6/;t loopb
s/9\n1\n/\n1\n9/;t loopb
s/9\n\n/\n1\n8/;t loopb
s/\n1\n/\n\n1/;t loopb
s/\(.\)\n\n/\n\n\1/;t loopb
s/^\n\n//
H
g
s/[^\n]*\n//
s/\n//
```

(Much easier in awk thought.)

Note: I once saw a Turing Machine implementation is sed, so I try to remember that anything that can be done with a programming language can be done in sed.  That of course does not mean that sed is the good tool in all situations.

Comment: I haven't tried to understand this but based on your comment it seems this will fail for anything but one digit numbers.  You can't replace only the last number in isolation.

Comment: I know that I can't replace only the last number in isolation.  This is why I have 2 `\n`.  For the multiplication, right of it is the solution, and in the middle the carry digit.

Comment: I’ve been having trouble implementing a similar arithmetic loop in `sed` (for the challenge, not for a practical purpose). The first `t` instruction always seems to succeed. `t` is defined as branching “*if any substitutions have been made since the most recent reading of an input line or execution of a t.*”, which is true after the initial `s/$/\n\n/` instruction. So, if the last digit isn’t `0`, no multiplication happens.

Comment: Turing machine in `sed` ? Wow!

Answer (score 7):

Perl is useful here:

```
perl -pe '
  s{(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)}
   {$1 . $2/2 . $3 . $4/2 . $5 . $6*2 . $7 . $8*2}e
' file
```

If you want to edit your files in-place, perl has a `-i` option like sed.

Comment: You mean that *sed* has the `-i` option like *perl*, not the other way around. You will not find a `-i` option in the required list of options in the POSIX spec for *sed*, BTW, but rather only occasionally  and unofficially in certain vendor ports.  READ: `sed -i` **is not universally supported**, although `perl -i` is.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible. See e.g. http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/sed/sed_15.html.

However if you only have a small set of possible values for block, size, start, and length, it might be quickest to hard-code the needed substitutions.  The next-easiest option is probably to use `awk`, but that can't modify files in-place.