# Extracting numbers with sed without using repetition modifiers ( +, ?, {m} )

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have something like this:

```
plym    fury    77      73      2500
chevy   nova    79      60      3000
ford    mustang 65      45      10000
volvo   gl      78      102     9850
ford    ltd     83      15      10500
chevy   nova    80      50      3500
fiat    600     65      115     450
honda   accord  81      30      6000
ford    thundbd 84      10      17000
toyota  tercel  82      180     750
chevy   impala  65      85      1550
ford    bronco  83      25      9500
```

and I need to create a list that show all the cars that cost less than $10,000, except Chevys.  The list should be sorted from lowest cost to highest .

I must use `sed` with quit option and regular expression (DO NOT use repetition)

so far I have this

```
grep -iv "chevy" cars | sort -nk 5 | sed '/regex$/ q'
```

I'm having a problem with the regex WITHOUT repetition.

Comment: can you edit your question to include an example of what you mean by repetition. Good luck.

Comment: Hi shelter, I'm not sure what meas without repetition either :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this homework?

- Since you're already sorting in ascending order of cost, you just need
  to stop grabbing lines when the cost becomes five digits.
- `sed
  '/regex$/q'` will stop (because of the `q` (*quit*) command) when
  whatever `regex$` is matches.
- You've already got a `$` there to match the end of
  line, so you just need something in `regex` that represents five
  arbitrary characters (or digits if you think that's better).
- <strike>Afterwards, you'll need a few more piped commands to get just the car names (see `cut`) and remove duplicates (see `sort -u` and/or `uniq`)</strike>

*Follow up to comment:*

I'm now assuming that by *repetition* you mean that don't want your regex pattern to comprise of repeats (i.e. `[a-z][a-z][a-z]`).  (I'd initially thought that you meant you didn't want duplicate car names so I've now striked that part out.)

You'll probably be interested in these syntax:

Along with:

- `?` - zero or one
- `*` - zero or many
- `+` - one or many

There's also:

- `{n}` - exactly `n` times
- `{n,}` - `n` or more times.
- `{n,m}` - `n` to `m` times.

You'll also probably want to specify `-r` when using these so that you don't have to escape everything.  (e.g. `sed -r '[a-z]{3}'` as opposed to `sed '[a-z]\{3\}'`.

See *REGULAR EXPRESSIONS* under `man egrep` for more information about the egrep syntax (which `sed` uses).

Comment: thanks antak, the problem that I'm having it's precisely with regex, I don't know what to put there without using repetitions :-(

Comment: Thanks antak
I forgot to answer your very first question, yes this is homework
I tried:
> grep -iv "chevy" cars.txt | sort -nk 5 | sed -r '/[0-9]{5,}$/ q'
and it works when I running myself however since I'm also running this command through my professor script and it doesn't I think the script only accept one correct answer. I'm not sure what means "without repetition neither"

Comment: I dunno, you'll have to ask your professor.  But here're some points to note: You don't need the space between `/ q`, and the comma in `{5,}` isn't technically needed (because it's sorted).

Comment: Hi antak thanks a lot for your help! I found the answer (the one that the script accepted) and I must said it's kind of disappointed

> grep -iv "chevy" cars | sort -nk 5 | sed '/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/q'

Answer (score 2):

You could do this much more simply using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '!/chevy/ && $NF < 10000 { print | "sort -nk 5" }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
fiat    600     65      115     450
toyota  tercel  82      180     750
plym    fury    77      73      2500
honda   accord  81      30      6000
ford    bronco  83      25      9500
volvo   gl      78      102     9850
```

Update:

Here's one way using `GNU sed`:

```
< file.txt sort -nk 5 | sed -nre '/chevy/d' -e '/.* [0-9]{,4}$/p'
```

Results:

```
fiat    600     65      115     450
toyota  tercel  82      180     750
plym    fury    77      73      2500
honda   accord  81      30      6000
ford    bronco  83      25      9500
volvo   gl      78      102     9850
```

Comment: Thanks steve, I appreciate you answer, but I would like to use sed since I'm learning it

Comment: @juanp_1982: Please see the update. I don't think you can, could or should use `sed`'s quit option. HTH.

Comment: thanks! that works! but I'm running my professor script to validate my command and doesn't like it, I must use sed with quit. the idea is that when find the regex quit showing the output. it also complain about no using repetition (I'm not sure what it means)

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` and `GNU sort` :

```
awk '!/chevy/{if($5 < 10000){print}}' file.txt | sort -n -k 5
```

---

**output**

```
fiat    600     65      115     450
toyota  tercel  82      180     750
plym    fury    77      73      2500
honda   accord  81      30      6000
ford    bronco  83      25      9500
volvo   gl      78      102     9850
```

---

`sed` is not designed to make arithmetic expressions. Some guys have had try there [Sed substitution possible with arithmetic involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958839/sed-substitution-possible-with-arithmetic-involved)

---

**ANOTHER SOLUTION** using `Perl`, tested on `Minix` & `Archlinux` (very portable)

```
perl -lane '
    END{for (sort {$a<=>$b} keys %h) {print $h{$_}}}
    $h{$F[-1] . " " . $F[1]} = join "\t", @F
        if $F[-1] < 10000 && $F[1] ne "chevy"
' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks sputnick, I appreciate you answer, but I would like to use sed since I'm learning it